# Proof of $gcd(f_{n},f_{n+2})=1$ for natural numbers

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

I'm going to use the Principle of Mathematical Induction to prove the above statement.

Base cases:

$(n=1)$ $f_{1}=1, f_{3}=2$ so $gcd(1,2)=1$

$(n=2)$ $f_{2}=1, f_{4}=3$ so $gcd(1,3)=1$

Assume that $gcd(f_{n}, f_{n+2})=1$ holds for some natural numbers. I want to show that $gcd(f_{n+1}，f_{n+3}=1)$

Let $d=gcd(f_{n+1}, f_{n+3})$, then $d|f_{n+1}$ and $d|f_{n+3}$

Therefore, $d|f_{n+3}-f_{n+1}$, so $d|f_{n+2}$, and by the inductive hypothesis...

I don't know how to proceed from then on. Can anyone shed some light on continuing the proof from here?

Comment: Do you mean the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: $f_{n+2}=f_{n}+f_{n+1}$ therefor $f_n=f_{n+2}-f_{n+1}$, then ...

Comment: Yes the Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this. Suppose $d\gt 1$ divides $f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n+3}$. Argue exactly as you did that $d$ divides $f_{n+2}$. Then argue in basically the same way that $d$ divides $f_n$. But by the induction hypothesis this is false, for $\gcd(f_n,f_{n+2})=1$.